# How to mix primary survey data set with a secondary data set in SPSS?

Tags: spss

I am currently working on my master's thesis which aims to explain the different levels of popularity among music festivals. To do this I distributed a survey asking festival attendees of the ten biggest Dutch music festivals how they rated certain aspects of the festival. This survey had one multiple-response question to ask which festivals the respondents visited last year. The survey would continue with questions about aspects of the festival. I used the data to create 6 different independent variables (line-up, side programming, location, atmosphere, escapism, and social). Now the problem arises when adding the dependent variable for the popularity of the music festival. This variable has not been derived from the data set, but rather from secondary data based on tickets sold, social interaction, and festival capacity. Since it has not been derived from the data set it does not fit the same dimension as the other data. The rows in my data set correspond with the respondents I get out of the survey, while the rows for my popularity score should correspond with the ten festivals I am studying. Do any of you have a solution to this problem? My initial goal is to run a multiple regression analysis between these variables which will explain why some festivals are more popular than others (for example because they have a better atmosphere).

- I have tried to add the popularity variable by hand as 1 number.
- I have tried to distract the independent variable from my dataset and create a new one with the festivals as rows and the popularity included. This resulted in the loss of my raw data.

Comment: Welcome to Stack-Overflow! Your problem can probably solved with a little resructuring and the `match files` function. BUT - in order to help you we'd need to understand the structure of you two datasets, especially how you code the identity of the dependent variable. Please edit your post to add this information, and while you're at it, please remove from the question all the extra text that doesn't contribute to understanding the core pogramming problem.